# Python shuffle list not working

Tags: python

I am new with python. coming from a C++ background I'm ironically having trouble understanding the simplicity of this language not to mention how IDLE works.

anyhow I need to write a simple function that takes a list and returns a new list with the elements inside it shuffled

this is what I have so far

```
import random
def shuffle():
    aList = []
    i = 0
    for i in range(0, 5):
        elements = input(": ")
        aList.append(elements)

    shuffleList = random.shuffle(aList)
    return shuffleList


shuffle()
```

and after I enter the elements(numerical numbers in this case), nothing outputs.. So the shuffleList for some reason is not being shown in there. Any ideas ?

> ```
> >>> 
> : 1
> : 2
> : 3
> : 4
> : 5
> >>>
> ```

Comment: You don't need to initialize the iterative variable before the loop.

Comment: Don't bother with IDLE if it doesn't suit you. Do install IPython, as the IPython console is far superior to the default REPL.

Comment: I'd go with Sublime. More aesthetic, very functional.

Comment: I have to use IDLE since it's a school requirement. I don't like the fact that I have to call the function in shell instead of just pressing run.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle) shuffles the list in place, and its output is `None`.

Since you store and return its output in `shuffleList = random.shuffle(aList)`, nothing is printed.

So instead, return the `aList` back:

```
import random
def shuffle():
    aList = []
    i = 0
    for i in range(0, 5):
        elements = input(": ")
        aList.append(elements)
    random.shuffle(aList)
    return aList
```

Answer (score 3):

[`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle) works [in place](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm), meaning it updates the provided parameter, rather than returning a value (other than the default, `None`). In C++, you would need to pass a reference to the list instead (e.g. `int** aList`), but in Python this distinction doesn't really exist.

So, you're actually setting `shuffleList` to `None`, and then returning it!

You can confirm this by using `print` to actually show the results when you're finished - just returning the value from the function won't output anything, as far as I am aware:

```
results = shuffle()
print results
```

To fix it, just return `aList`, instead of storing the result in another variable:

```
random.shuffle(aList)
return aList
```

Answer (score 2):

`random.shuffle` is an in-place operation, it does not return anything

```
>>> l
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

>>> random.shuffle(l)
>>> l
[0, 3, 1, 4, 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

Shuffle shuffles the list, it doesn't return a new list. Try this:

```
import random

def shuffle():
    aList = []

    for i in range(0, 5):
        elements = input(": ")
        aList.append(elements)

    random.shuffle(aList)
    return aList

print shuffle()
```

Comment: You are printing the function which does not work. returning th elist is enough. I believe thats the problem

Comment: I added the print after the downvotes started rolling in and this willwork by the way. You're just printing a list.

Answer (score 1):

`random.shuffle()` reorders the list in-place and returns None.