# Append to list after shuffle (Python)

Tags: python, append, shuffle

Newby question:
I'm having trouble figuring out why the code below doesn't work. I'm trying to make a nested list wherein each of the 10 nested lists is in a different order. What I get instead is the same list repeated 10 times in the same order.

So I want:
[[1, 2, 4, 3], [4, 2, 3, 1], [2, 4, 3, 1]]

but I get:
[[2, 3, 1, 4], [2, 3, 1, 4], [2, 3, 1, 4]]

```
<pre>from random import shuffle

myList = ["file1", "file2", "file3", "file4"]
longList = []

for x in range(0,10):
    shuffle(myList)
    longList.append(myList)

print(longList)<code>
```

Thanks in advance!

D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the object references inside the `longList` are all to the object `myList`.

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28463726/python-shuffle-list-not-working), [random.shuffle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle) changes `myList` in place, so each time you call [random.shuffle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle) on it, it overwrites its content.

A solution can be to clone the list each time you shuffle it and several ways are available for this ([How to clone a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list-in-python)).

In the following code I choose to slice it :

```
from random import shuffle

myList = ["file1", "file2", "file3", "file4"]
longList = []

for x in range(0,10):
    shuffle(myList)
    longList.append(myList[:])
```

Comment: Every time I encounter a problem like this, I think to myself "That's the last time that's catching me out!". Nope.

Comment: Ah! Of course! Makes perfect sense, now. Thanks, Pierre!

Answer (score 1):

Shuffle works inplace, its returning None.
It's weird that it's returning same list in a 10 times try. It's possible that you are not doing that enough times, so shuffle returns same results few times in a raw. try to test that for a large number of times.
Maybe do:

```
random.seed(x)
```

inside the loop.

Comment: This was `random.shuffle`?? OH man I totally did not realize it was *that* shuffle...ugh... OK. I'm deleting mine. +1. Thanks for bringing that up, btw.

Comment: Thanks! I have a workaround which is to write each line to a file by putting the shuffle line in side a "with open..." line and then writing to the file on each iteration.
But why the above works and my original code doesn't is a mystery to me! (http://pastebin.com/A2p1gXSQ)

Comment: @user2011285 Putting code in the comments like that is really not easy to look at. You can make a pastebin of your code. http://pastebin.com/